# Downloading from google cloud storage with api client library fails with HTTP 416

Tags: python, download, google-api-python-client

unfortunately I don't want to rely on additional packages except of the `googleapiclient` one and facing some issue on downloading objects from a storage bucket.

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import googleapiclient.discovery

storage_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    serviceName='storage', version='v1', credentials=creds)

f = storage_service.objects()
results = f.list(bucket='MYBUCKET').execute()

for d in results['items']:
    with open(d['name']), 'wb') as fh:
        req = MediaIoBaseDownload(
            fh,
            f.get_media(bucket=d['bucket'], object=d['name'], generation=d['generation']),
            chunksize=1024*1024
        )
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = req.next_chunk()
```

Now this yieldds the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-210-d66ce751dec5> in <module>()
      4         done = False
      5         while done is False:
----> 6             status, done = req.next_chunk()

path_to_my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129                     logger.warning(message)
--> 130             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    131         return positional_wrapper
    132 

path_to_my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.pyc in next_chunk(self, num_retries)
    703       return MediaDownloadProgress(self._progress, self._total_size), self._done
    704     else:
--> 705       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)
    706 
    707 

HttpError: <HttpError 416 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o/MYOBJECT?generation=1234&alt=media returned "Requested range not satisfiable">
```

Is somebody aware of what I'm missing somewhere or what is best practice to download files from storage? Everything I found relies on storage specific libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/15).

Some of the files (most) are 0-byte files.

Problem is fixed by the following code:

```
for d in results['items']:
    request = f.get_media(bucket=d['bucket'], object=d['name'], generation=d['generation'])
    response = request.execute()
    if response != '':
        with open(d['name']), 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(response)
```